# Remove Corrupt Start of Json in Python

Tags: python, json, string

Hi I am using a python script to scrape stock price information from the Australian Stock Exchange (JSON format). Most of them have information available from this page source as an example
https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/share/tcl

Some however aren't but a subset of information (which is better than nothing) is available from https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/share/tcl/prices?interval=daily&count=1

The first url I have no issue going through and pulling the elements from the json however the second one I can't get any of the elements. I believe the issue is that the second one has "{"data":[" at the start. I have tried stripping first nine characters (and last 2) but that results in a not subscriptable object error.

```
{"data":[{"code":"TCL","close_date":"2021-05-07T00:00:00+1000","close_price":14,"change_price":-0.1,"volume":2945117,"day_high_price":14.05,"day_low_price":13.87,"change_in_percent":"-0.709%"}]}
```

For comparison the response from the first one which works is

```
{"code":"TCL","isin_code":"AU000000TCL6","desc_full":"Fully Paid Ordinary/units Stapled Securities","last_price":14,"open_price":13.96,"day_high_price":14.05,"day_low_price":13.87,"change_price":-0.1,"change_in_percent":"-0.709%","volume":2945117,"bid_price":13.95,"offer_price":14.05,"previous_close_price":14.1,"previous_day_percentage_change":"0.356%","year_high_price":15.635,"last_trade_date":"2021-05-07T00:00:00+1000","year_high_date":"2020-11-11T00:00:00+1100","year_low_price":12.36,"year_low_date":"2021-02-26T00:00:00+1100","year_open_price":6.91537,"year_open_date":"2014-02-25T11:00:00+1100","year_change_price":7.08463,"year_change_in_percentage":"102.448%","pe":0,"eps":-0.264,"average_daily_volume":4870346,"annual_dividend_yield":2.21,"market_cap":38607345120,"number_of_shares":2738109583,"deprecated_market_cap":38333534000,"deprecated_number_of_shares":2738109583,"suspended":false}
```

a subset of my code that I have split out for testing is as follows

```
import requests
import json
import datetime

x = requests.get('https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/share/tcl/prices?interval=daily&count=1')

if 'close_date' in x.json():
    print(x.json()['close_date'][:10])

if 'close_price' in x.json():
    print(x.json()['close_price'])

if 'change_in_percent' in x.json():
    print(x.json()['change_in_percent'])
```

When run I don't get any error but it doesn't print those values even though they are in the json

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated. I believe that starting 9 characters and last 2 in the response is what my issue is (but could be very wrong). I feel like I almost like I need to convert the json to a string, clean it and then convert it back to a json but searching hasn't given me any direction that has helped.

Comment: _it doesn't print those values even though they are in the json_ Yes they are, but they're not at the top level.  They're nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of calling `x.json` multiple, times, I'd do it only once.
Also, I believe, from what you have given us, that you can just index into `['data']` and it would work.

```py
info = x.json()['data'][0] # Index into data and then get first element of list (since there is a list)
```

However, this would only work on second link.
You can always use errorhandlers to make sure that this always works though.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I wouldn't be able to use index as my full code uses a link to sql database to pull full list of about 20 stocks and then goes through and pulls these value. The order of the json and also the quantity of items does vary from stock to stock.

Comment: @Craig No problem! There probably is a pattern in their API. You will just have to search for it. But I'm assuming that there will only be 2-3 ways to search for each stock. You can use an errorhandler for that.

Comment: Think I have found it thanks to 12944querty. The following appears to work as intended (x.json()['data'][0])['close_price']